# How to remove an extra “hundreds” when converting numbers to text?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert numbers to text.

Ex.
1,112,589.63 = ONE MILLION ONE HUNDRED TWELVE THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED EIGHTY NINE 63/100

My function

```
Option Explicit
  'MAIN FUNCTION

'=SPELLNUMBER(95)
Sub TEST()
  MsgBox SPELLNUMBER(95)
End Sub

Function SPELLNUMBER(MYNUMBER, Optional BMONEY = False)
  Dim DOLLARS, CENTS, TEMP
  Dim DECIMALPLACE, COUNT
  Dim INUMBER

  ReDim PLACE(9) As String
  PLACE(1) = " HUNDRED "
  PLACE(2) = " THOUSAND "
  PLACE(3) = " MILLION "
  PLACE(4) = " BILLION "
  PLACE(5) = " TRILLION "

INUMBER = MYNUMBER
' STRING REPRESENTATION OF AMOUNT.
MYNUMBER = Trim(Str(MYNUMBER))

' POSITION OF DECIMAL PLACE 0 IF NONE.
DECIMALPLACE = InStr(MYNUMBER, ".")
' CONVERT CENTS AND SET MYNUMBER TO DOLLAR AMOUNT.
If DECIMALPLACE > 0 Then
    CENTS = Right(FormatCurrency(MYNUMBER, 2), 2) & "/100"
  MYNUMBER = Trim(Left(MYNUMBER, DECIMALPLACE - 1))
End If

COUNT = 1
Do While MYNUMBER <> ""
    TEMP = GETHUNDREDS(Right(MYNUMBER, 3))
    If TEMP <> "" Then DOLLARS = TEMP & PLACE(COUNT) & DOLLARS
    If Len(MYNUMBER) > 3 Then
        MYNUMBER = Left(MYNUMBER, Len(MYNUMBER) - 3)
    Else
        MYNUMBER = ""
    End If
    COUNT = COUNT + 1
Loop

If BMONEY = True Then
  Select Case DOLLARS
    Case ""
      DOLLARS = "NO DOLLARS"
    Case "ONE"
      DOLLARS = "ONE DOLLAR"
    Case Else
     DOLLARS = DOLLARS & " DOLLARS"
End Select

Select Case CENTS
  Case ""
   CENTS = " AND NO CENTS"
  Case "ONE"
    CENTS = " AND ONE CENT"
  Case Else
    CENTS = " AND " & CENTS & " CENTS"
End Select
End If
SPELLNUMBER = DOLLARS & CENTS
End Function


Function GETHUNDREDS(ByVal MYNUMBER)
  Dim RESULT As String
  If Val(MYNUMBER) = 0 Then Exit Function
  MYNUMBER = Right("000" & MYNUMBER, 3)
  ' CONVERT THE HUNDREDS PLACE.
  If Mid(MYNUMBER, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
      RESULT = GETDIGIT(Mid(MYNUMBER, 1, 1)) & " HUNDRED "
  End If
  ' CONVERT THE TENS AND ONES PLACE.
  If Mid(MYNUMBER, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
      RESULT = RESULT & GETTENS(Mid(MYNUMBER, 2))
  Else
      RESULT = RESULT & GETDIGIT(Mid(MYNUMBER, 3))
  End If
  GETHUNDREDS = RESULT
End Function

Function GETTENS(TENSTEXT)
  Dim RESULT As String
  RESULT = "" ' NULL OUT THE TEMPORARY FUNCTION VALUE.
  If Val(Left(TENSTEXT, 1)) = 1 Then   ' IF VALUE BETWEEN 10-19...
      Select Case Val(TENSTEXT)
          Case 10: RESULT = "TEN"
          Case 11: RESULT = "ELEVEN"
          Case 12: RESULT = "TWELVE"
          Case 13: RESULT = "THIRTEEN"
          Case 14: RESULT = "FOURTEEN"
          Case 15: RESULT = "FIFTEEN"
          Case 16: RESULT = "SIXTEEN"
          Case 17: RESULT = "SEVENTEEN"
          Case 18: RESULT = "EIGHTEEN"
          Case 19: RESULT = "NINETEEN"
          Case Else
      End Select
  Else ' IF VALUE BETWEEN 20-99...
      Select Case Val(Left(TENSTEXT, 1))
          Case 2: RESULT = "TWENTY "
          Case 3: RESULT = "THIRTY "
          Case 4: RESULT = "FORTY "
          Case 5: RESULT = "FIFTY "
          Case 6: RESULT = "SIXTY "
          Case 7: RESULT = "SEVENTY "
          Case 8: RESULT = "EIGHTY "
          Case 9: RESULT = "NINETY "
          Case Else
      End Select
      RESULT = RESULT & GETDIGIT _
          (Right(TENSTEXT, 1))  ' RETRIEVE ONES PLACE.
  End If
  GETTENS = RESULT
End Function

Function GETDIGIT(DIGIT)
  Select Case Val(DIGIT)
      Case 1: GETDIGIT = "ONE"
      Case 2: GETDIGIT = "TWO"
      Case 3: GETDIGIT = "THREE"
      Case 4: GETDIGIT = "FOUR"
      Case 5: GETDIGIT = "FIVE"
      Case 6: GETDIGIT = "SIX"
      Case 7: GETDIGIT = "SEVEN"
      Case 8: GETDIGIT = "EIGHT"
      Case 9: GETDIGIT = "NINE"
      Case Else: GETDIGIT = ""
  End Select
End Function
```

I get at the end the word HUNDRED.

Ex.
1,112,589.63 = ONE MILLION ONE HUNDRED TWELVE THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED EIGHTY NINE HUNDRED 63/100

How do I get rid of the HUNDRED at the end before my decimals?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the `GETHUNDREDS` function does?

Comment: I am so sorry to not be able to explain this one, as i have no previous training on VBA, thats why I am asking for some help in the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need hundred in your `Places` variable.

What you would have is

```
Ones
Thousands
Millions
...
```

But since `Ones` is irrelevant you can just leave that place empty.

Comment: Thank you so much, so simple i couldn't see it

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks to @arcadeprecinct the function will look like this and will be solved

```
ReDim PLACE(9) As String
  PLACE(1) = " "
  PLACE(2) = " THOUSAND "
  PLACE(3) = " MILLION "
  PLACE(4) = " BILLION "
  PLACE(5) = " TRILLION "
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))
'change to the above sentence in convert cents section

' CONVERT CENTS AND SET MYNUMBER TO DOLLAR AMOUNT.
If DECIMALPLACE > 0 Then
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    CENTS = Right(FormatCurrency(MYNUMBER, 2), 2) & "/100"  <<<

## 'new and correct module list as below:

Option Explicit
' Workbook open event
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub
'Main Function
Function ChqText(ByVal Myinput) As String

```
Dim Temp, TempA, MyinputA, MyinputB, MyinputC As String

Dim digitvalue, integer1, integer2, Place As String
Dim digitlength, J As Integer
Place = "仙角元拾佰仟萬拾佰仟億拾佰仟萬"
integer1 = "壹貳參肆伍陸柒捌玖"
integer2 = "正整零元零零零萬零零零億零零零萬"

digitvalue = ""
If Myinput < 0 Then digitvalue = "負"
Myinput = Int(Abs(Myinput) * 100 + 0.5)
If Myinput > 999999999999999# Then
  ChqText = "數字太大了！"
  Exit Function
End If
If Myinput = 0 Then
  ChqText = "零元零仙"
  Exit Function
End If

MyinputA = Trim(Str(Myinput))
digitlength = Len(MyinputA)
For J = 1 To digitlength
MyinputB = Mid(MyinputA, J, 1) & MyinputB
Next
For J = 1 To digitlength
  Temp = Val(Mid(MyinputB, J, 1))
  If Temp = 0 Then
     MyinputC = Mid(integer2, J, 1) & MyinputC
  Else
     MyinputC = Mid(integer1, Temp, 1) & Mid(Place, J, 1) & MyinputC
  End If
Next

digitlength = Len(MyinputC)
For J = 1 To digitlength - 1
  If Mid(MyinputC, J, 1) = "零" Then
     Select Case Mid(MyinputC, J + 1, 1)
        Case "零", "元", "萬", "億", "正":
        MyinputC = Left(MyinputC, J - 1) & Mid(MyinputC, J + 1, 30)
        J = J - 1
     End Select
  End If
Next

digitlength = Len(MyinputC)
For J = 1 To digitlength - 1
   If Mid(MyinputC, J, 1) = "億" And Mid(MyinputC, J + 1, 1) = "萬" Then
     MyinputC = Left(MyinputC, J) & Mid(MyinputC, J + 2, 30)
     Exit For
   End If
Next

ChqText = digitvalue & Trim(MyinputC)
```

End Function

'Main Function

Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)

Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp

Dim DecimalPlace, Count

ReDim Place(9) As String

Place(2) = " Thousand "

Place(3) = " Million "

Place(4) = " Billion "

Place(5) = " Trillion "

' String representation of amount.

MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

' Position of decimal place 0 if none.

DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.

If DecimalPlace > 0 Then

Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2))

MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))

End If

Count = 1

Do While MyNumber <> ""

Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))

If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars

If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then

MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)

Else

MyNumber = ""

End If

Count = Count + 1

Loop

Select Case Dollars

Case ""

Dollars = "No Dollars"

Case "One"

Dollars = "One Dollar"

Case Else

Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"

End Select

Select Case Cents

Case ""

Cents = " and No Cents"

Case "One"

Cents = " and One Cent"

Case Else

Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"

End Select

SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents

End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text

Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)

Dim Result As String

If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function

MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

' Convert the hundreds place.

If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then

Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "

End If

' Convert the tens and ones place.

If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then

Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))

Else

Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))

End If

GetHundreds = Result

End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.

Function GetTens(TensText)

Dim Result As String

Result = "" ' Null out the temporary function value.

If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then ' If value between 10-19...

Select Case Val(TensText)

Case 10: Result = "Ten"

Case 11: Result = "Eleven"

Case 12: Result = "Twelve"

Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"

Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"

Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"

Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"

Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"

Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"

Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"

Case Else

End Select

Else ' If value between 20-99...

Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))

Case 2: Result = "Twenty "

Case 3: Result = "Thirty "

Case 4: Result = "Forty "

Case 5: Result = "Fifty "

Case 6: Result = "Sixty "

Case 7: Result = "Seventy "

Case 8: Result = "Eighty "

Case 9: Result = "Ninety "

Case Else

End Select

Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(TensText, 1)) ' Retrieve ones place.

End If

GetTens = Result

End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.

Function GetDigit(Digit)

Select Case Val(Digit)

Case 1: GetDigit = "One"

Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"

Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"

Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"

Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"

Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"

Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"

Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"

Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"

Case Else: GetDigit = ""

End Select

End Function

'Function TCMny(Mny As String) As String

'=========將金額數值轉成中文金額至兆位==============

'

'==============================================================================

'目前只轉換至兆位數億元止

Function TCMny(Mny As String) As String

```
  Dim ReturnC As String

  Dim Cunit(), CunitP(), Cnumb(), MnyA() As String

  Dim i, numberLen, oneN, nN, sN As Integer

  Dim NP As Boolean



  ReturnC = ""

  'Cunit = Array("元", "拾", "佰", "仟", "萬", "拾", "佰", "仟", "億", "拾", "佰", "仟", "兆")

  CunitP = Array("分", "角", ".", "元", "拾", "佰", ",", "仟", "萬", "拾", ",", "佰", "仟", "億", ",", "拾", "佰", "仟", ",", "兆", "拾", "佰", ",", "仟")

  Cnumb = Array("零", "壹", "貳", "參", "肆", "伍", "陸", "柒", "捌", "玖")



  '金額不格式化小數第二位零時會被省略,致使無法取得一致的格式

  '所以用format產一個與CunitP相同對應的格式

  Mny = Format(Mny, "#,##0.00")

  'ReDim MnyA(Len(Mny) - 1)



  'For i = 0 To UBound(MnyA)

  '   MnyA(i) = Mid(Mny, Len(Mny) - i, 1)

  'Next

        'MsgBox "len=" & Mny



     For i = 0 To Len(Mny) - 1

        'MsgBox "len=" & Len(Mny)

        '不理 0 . ,

        If Mid(Mny, i + 1, 1) = "." Or Mid(Mny, i + 1, 1) = "," Then

           sN = i   '欺騙用

        Else

            If Mid(Mny, i + 1, 1) <> "0" Then

                ReturnC = ReturnC + Cnumb(Val(Mid(Mny, i + 1, 1)))

                'MsgBox Val(Mid(Mny, i + 1, 1)) & "  " & i

                ReturnC = ReturnC + CunitP(Len(Mny) - i - 1)

            Else

                If Len(Mny) - i = 20 Then

                    ReturnC = ReturnC + "兆"

                End If

                If Len(Mny) - i = 14 Then

                    ReturnC = ReturnC + "億"

                End If

                If Len(Mny) - i = 9 Then

                    ReturnC = ReturnC + "萬"

                End If

                If Len(Mny) - i = 4 Then

                    ReturnC = ReturnC + "元"

                End If

             End If

        End If

     Next i





      ReturnC = ReturnC + "整"

  '//ShowMessage(ReturnC);

  'return ReturnC;

  TCMny = ReturnC
```

End Function

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your answer to make it more readable (indent source code with 4 spaces)